# How to throttle jigdo-lite's download rate

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, downloads, wget

By using this command:
`jigdo-lite --noask http://cdimage.debian.org/image`

jigdo issues a call to wget like this

`/bin/sh /usr/bin/wget --user-agent=jigdo-lite/0.7.3 (GNU Wget 1.17.1 built on linux-gnu.; ) --passive-ftp --dot-style=mega --continue --timeout=30 http://cdimage.debian.org/image`

jigdo doesn't include any parameter for download speed limit, so I tried temporarily replacing wget by a script, like this:

```
sudo mv /usr/bin/wget /usr/bin/wgetto #I rename wget
echo '/usr/bin/wgetto --limit-rate=500k ${1}' | sudo tee /usr/bin/wget #and replace it with this single liner
chmod +x /usr/bin/wget
```

but the problem is I can't have all those parameters jigdo sends to wget properly interpreted by my script. Also tried ${@} and several other combinations, to no avail.

Comment: If your question is about Debian, you're better off asking at https://unix.stackexchange.com.

Comment: No, it's not Debian related. Jigdo is a general purpose download tool included in Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2):

Had same question and found a workaround while on tdlp[1](https://tldp.org/HOWTO/Debian-Jigdo/downloadingyourfirstimage.html). jigdo-lite (0.7.3 here) writes user choices in `~/.jigdo-lite`, whitch contains a `wgetOpts=` string. Putting `--limit-rate=xxx`
there worked for me.

jigdo-lite have to be executed at least once first, but then it works. Wget man page also instruct about that option (lots of small files might not trigger the throttle efficiently)

Bye.

1. [The Linux documentation project](https://tldp.org/HOWTO/Debian-Jigdo/downloadingyourfirstimage.html)